# how to efficient paging in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, database

I want to sort all docs by field `x` (multiple docs can **have same value** on this field). Then every time I press "next", it loads the 10 more docs.

If multiple docs have the **same value**, they can be displayed at **whatever order** among them, it doesn't matter.

Since `skip()` is inefficient on large dataset, how do this efficiently? No pagination number needed, only infinite scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require pagination number, then you can just utilise a monotonically increasing unique `id` values; such as `_id` with [ObjectId()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Using your example:

```
/* Value of first scroll record, and to be updated every iteration */
var current_id;

var scroll_size = 10; 

db.collection.find({_id: {$lt: current_id}}).
                    limit(scroll_size).
                    sort({
                           _id: -1, 
                             x: 1   // Depending on your use case
                    });
```

The example above will give you most recent records. Depending on your use case you would have to decide what to do with newly inserted document.

If you are using a different field than `_id` to scroll through, make sure you add appropriate [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on the field.

Comment: But this doesn't give records that are are sorted by x, right? This is sorted by _id

Comment: As you can see in the example of `sort()`, the result is sorted by both `_id` AND `x`. You can also try to either A) include `x` in the matching part alongside `_id` or B) only use 'x' in the matching part. What is the value of 'x' ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar Yes, it's sorted by `x` but if sorting by `x` changes the order, this won't work correctly anymore as your `{_id: {$lt: current_id}` makes no sense anymore.